# How to modify map legend and data labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a bubble state map and have the following code. I need to modify this code so that the legend only shows the color spectrum and is titled Number of Mosquito Species" (note:need to get rid of the bubble legend). In addition, I would like to show data labels on each state that show the number of species for that state. Greatly appreciate your help.You can download the data `https://uploadnow.io/f/dbKCDFf`.

```
 # Plot the US map without state and count data labels
  Map6.1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = map_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = 
  group), color =     

 'gray', fill = NA, alpha = 0.35) +
 coord_map() +
 theme_void() +
 geom_point(data = region.lab.data, aes(x = long, y = lat, size   
 = Misquito_Species,   

fill = Misquito_Species), 
         shape = 21, color = "black") +

scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
scale_size(range = c(5, 14)) +

labs(size = "No of Misquito Species", title = "Number of   
Misquito Species by State    
- US") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold",hjust   
= 0.5, margin =    
margin(b = 20)))

Map6.1
```

Comment: If you don't get a helpful response, consider deleting this post and replacing it with a simpler example that's easier to reproduce.  There are a lot of built-in datasets that can probably serve your purposes.  And there are a lot of graphical elements that are unrelated too, such as the call to `labs()`.